# How do I mount a ZFS pool?

Tags: mount, zfs

Sorry for asking an Ubuntu concerning question, but I hope that someone here has some experience with that.

I have to mount the zfs pool I created with freenas8 on Ubuntu. I tried as it was described [in this *archived* Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171211140530/http://www.servercobra.com/freenas-to-ubuntu-initial-fileserver-setup-with-zfs). I was able to run this command without errors:

```
sudo zpool import data
```

and the status of my zpool is like this:

```
user@server:~$ sudo zpool status
  pool: data
 state: ONLINE
status: The pool is formatted using an older on-disk format.  The pool can
        still be used, but some features are unavailable.
action: Upgrade the pool using 'zpool upgrade'.  Once this is done, the
        pool will no longer be accessible on older software versions.
 scan: none requested
config:

        NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        data        ONLINE       0     0     0
          sda2      ONLINE       0     0     0
          sdb2      ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

so it looks good to me. but, i dont know how to access the pool. in my eyes i have to mount it, but i dont know how.

Comment: btw, you link was shorted so I could not follow it to have a look at the guide you were using, can you post the full link so we can fix this?

Comment: Do not run `zpool import pool`. This will import your pools using /dev/sd? which will lead to problems the next time you rearrange your drives. Use `zpool import -d /dev/disk/by-id data` instead.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you run the command `sudo zfs get all` it should list all the properties of you current zfs pools and file systems. One of those properties, if correctly set, should be ***mountpoint=***.

[image]

Zfs will mount the pool automatically, unless you are using legacy mounts, ***mountpoint*** tells zfs where the pool should be mounted in your system by default. If not set you can do so with

```
sudo zfs set mountpoint=/foo_mount data
```

That will make zfs mount your *data* pool in to a designated *foo_mount* point of your choice.

After that is done and since *root* owns the mount point you can change the owner of the mount with

```
sudo chown -R user:user /foo_mount
```

That will make the user *user* and the group *user* own the mount point and everything inside it, adjust the command to assign correct user:group privileges to the mount point.

Comment: Just to add, there is another property for _datasets_ `canmount` which can either be `on | off | noauto` _off_ and _noauto_ *prevent* auto-mounting as well for individual datasets.  For more info use `man zfs`.

Answer (score 20):

I had a similar *problem* and, indeed, `canmount` was `on` but the pool+dataset didn't mount on boot nor when going online, etc.

My solution, after `zpool import` and `zpool online` the pool, was:

1. `zfs mount poolname`
2. `zfs mount poolname/datasetname`

Yes, `zfs` instead of `zpool` with the poolname and then poolname/datasetname.

Hope this help someone.