# Mounting ZFS pool - almost there

Tags: mount, zfs

I'm having a bit of trouble mounting an ZFS pool I've migrated from a FreeNas system to Ubuntu 14.04.

So far I've managed to import the ZFS pool via the `zpool import Storage` command. I can list all the mount points with the `zfs list` command. My issue is I don't know how to mount these. Preferably permanently (or on startup).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

`zfs list`:

```
sudo zfs list                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      ⏎
NAME                       USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
Storage                    2.10T 3.09T  1.71G  /media/Storage
Storage/Others             12.9G 3.09T   232K  /media/Storage/Others
Storage/backup_osx         256K  3.09T   256K  /media/Storage/backup_osx
Storage/MyStuff            662G  3.09T   662G  /media/Storage/MyStuff
```

**Update**
So, I managed to sort it out myself. My problem was, that after I had run the `zpool import Storage` command, my disks wouldn't show up anywhere (nor should they!!!). After you import the ZFS Pool, you need to `mount` the drives. If you've installed [ZFS on Linux](http://zfsonlinux.org/) then you can run the `mountall` command and the mountpoints will be mounted in your system.

*A bit of trivia*

If you take a look at the `zfs list` i posted, the `NAME` corresponds to (in my case) the user's drive on the ZFS Raid array. The `MOUNTPOINT` corresponds to the place where you want your ZFS drive to show up.
So if you run `zfs set mountpoint=/media/Storage/Others Storage/Others` it will mount the Storage/Others "drive" in your /media/ folder. Note that you will need to mount the parent drive in order for anything to show up. I.e. I would need to mount `Storage` before being able to mount `Storage/Others`.

I hope this makes sense, if not, let me know and I will calrify. Also, someone with a bit more knowledge about this subject might find what I've written to be misleading, if so, let me know. This is just the way I understood it.

Also, [this thread helped me](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123126/how-do-i-mount-a-zfs-pool)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of `zpool status`.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify, `zpool import` alone doesn't import pools, you need to provide the name of the pool or import all pools with the `-a` parameter. If you do that, all datasets should be mounted automatically. You probably need create folders below the mountpoint that don't exist.

Comment: Thanks for you response LiveWireBT, my question was poorly worded. What I meant was, that I successfully imported my pool, but now had to mount it. I figured out how to do it all, and will add it to my question. Sorry for wasting your time :/