# how to recreate ZFS after upgrading to Ubuntu 16

Tags: server, zfs

I have a little nettop machine that's been running Ubuntu 14 server for a while, along w/ a USB3-attached RAID device which I formatted using ZFS (installed from http://zfsonlinux.org).

Setup's worked fine 'til I upgraded my server to Ubuntu 16, not realizing that ZFS had been formally baked into it! Now I need to rebuild/re-add my existing ZFS device without nuking the existing content.

Any pointers for how to do this with a minimum of risk?

(and, yes: I know I should've read the updates to v16 before upgrading. And, yes, I have a backup but it's a huge amount of data and I'd rather not have to restore it if I don't have to).

Comment: Maybe this answer might help?  http://askubuntu.com/a/123130/231142

Comment: Unfortunately, no - nothing is returned by 'get all'