# reading my zfs freenas pool

Tags: mount, raid, zfs

My freenas, failed somehow so I now boot my NAS on a live USB ubuntu to get my data.
These were on a RAID1 with 2x3To drives.
I used the following command from this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/182446/how-do-i-view-all-available-hdds-partitions):

```
sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL

NAME   FSTYPE      SIZE MOUNTPOINT LABEL
loop1  squashfs    1.4G /rofs      
sdb    zfs_member  2.7T            
├─sdb2 zfs_member  2.7T            Storage_pool
└─sdb1 zfs_member    2G            
loop0  ext2          4G            casper-rw
sdc                7.5G            
└─sdc1 vfat        7.5G /cdrom     UUI
sda    zfs_member  2.7T            
├─sda2 zfs_member  2.7T            Storage_pool
└─sda1 zfs_member    2G
```

So my drives are at least recognized
However when trying the zfs commands from this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123126/how-do-i-mount-a-zfs-pool) I do not get anything
sudo zpool status returns "no pools available" and "sudo zfs get all" just returns nothing.

Could you help me mount this pool ?
Thx

Answer (score 3):

Actually I realized I had forgotten to first run the command:

```
sudo zpool import data
```

This is now okay.