# How can I add a zfs drive pool to the Files gui?

Tags: 20.04, zfs

Ubuntu 20.04 up to date.
ZFS drive pool configured as /raid/

However this pool doesn't show up in the Files GUI as a location, just my two unpooled hard drives show up.

How can I get the pool to show up there (for ease of GUI controlled file access and operations)? Thanks.

Comment: Mount it to `/media/raid`

Comment: Tried that, got the following:

>>sudo mount /raid/ /media/raid

mount: /media/raid: /raid is not a block device.

Comment: This is a wrong usage of the command. Please [edit] your question and add output of `mount` command and also output of `cat /etc/fstab`.

Comment: Oh, already answered here. I had to configure the mount point in ZFS itself. Thanks.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/123126/how-do-i-mount-a-zfs-pool

Comment: The point is that only devices mounted under `/media` are shown in GUI.

Comment: Had to configure the mount point in zfs itself.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/123126/how-do-i-mount-a-zfs-pool

Answer (score 1):

Change mount point of your raid to something under `/media`, e.g `/media/raid`.