# Ubuntu Raid Array not working after a motherboard swap

Tags: raid, swap, motherboard

I have been using a raid 5 array as a NAS for past two years that I have created with the help of [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-raid-arrays-with-mdadm-on-ubuntu-16-04#creating-a-raid-5-array) guide. But recently I had to swap the motherboard of this system because the previous one stopped working. I have 1 nvme and 3 hdds in this system. Nvme is used as the system drive while 3 hdds used as the raid storage. System is booting fine into OS (without a fresh install of Ubuntu) after the motherboard is replaced. But the issue is raid array is not working anymore. 
I have no knowledge about Linux systems to recover this array. Things I already tried;

**Managed to recover data by just rebuilding the array from scratch. I did a fresh install of OMV and wiped 3 hdds using gui. Then created a new raid 5 array and it started resyncing. After resyncing is done files are accessible again.**

sudo mdadm --assemble /dev/md/NAS:0 /dev/sda /dev/sdb /dev/sdc
Output;

> mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sda
> mdadm: /dev/sda has no superblock - assembly aborted*

*This output is same to sda, sdb and sdc

```
cat /proc/mdstat
```

Output;

> Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5]
> [raid4] [raid10]
>  unused devices: none

```
lsblk -o NAME,SIZE,FSTYPE,TYPE,MOUNTPOINT
```

Output;

> NAME          SIZE FSTYPE     TYPE MOUNTPOINT
> loop0           4K squashfs   loop /snap/bare/5
> loop1         9.6M squashfs   loop /snap/canonical-livepatch/235
> loop2         9.6M squashfs   loop /snap/canonical-livepatch/246
> loop3       105.8M squashfs   loop /snap/core/16202
> loop4       105.8M squashfs   loop /snap/core/16091
> loop5        63.5M squashfs   loop /snap/core20/2015
> loop6        63.9M squashfs   loop /snap/core20/2105
> loop7        74.1M squashfs   loop /snap/core22/1033
> loop8       245.9M squashfs   loop /snap/firefox/3600
> loop9        73.9M squashfs   loop /snap/core22/864
> loop10        246M squashfs   loop /snap/firefox/3626
> loop11      349.7M squashfs   loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/143
> loop12      349.7M squashfs   loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/140
> loop13      496.9M squashfs   loop /snap/gnome-42-2204/132
> loop14        497M squashfs   loop /snap/gnome-42-2204/141
> loop15       81.3M squashfs   loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1534
> loop16       45.9M squashfs   loop /snap/snap-store/638
> loop17       91.7M squashfs   loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
> loop18       12.3M squashfs   loop /snap/snap-store/959
> loop19       40.4M squashfs   loop /snap/snapd/20671
> loop20       40.9M squashfs   loop /snap/snapd/20290
> loop21        452K squashfs   loop /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/83
> sda           3.6T zfs_member disk
> ├─sda1        128M            part
> └─sda2        3.6T ext4       part
> sdb           3.6T zfs_member disk
> ├─sdb1        128M            part
> └─sdb2        3.6T            part
> sdc           3.6T zfs_member disk
> ├─sdc1        128M            part
> └─sdc2        3.6T            part
> nvme0n1     119.2G            disk
> ├─nvme0n1p1   512M vfat       part /boot/efi
> └─nvme0n1p2 118.7G ext4       part /

```
cat /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
```

Output;

> mdadm.conf
> !NB! Run update-initramfs -u after updating this file.
> !NB! This will ensure that initramfs has an uptodate copy.
>
> Please refer to mdadm.conf(5) for information about this file.
>
> by default (built-in), scan all partitions (/proc/partitions) and all
> containers for MD superblocks. alternatively, specify devices to scan, using
> wildcards if desired.
> DEVICE partitions containers
>
> automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system
> HOMEHOST (system)
>
> instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts
> MAILADDR root
>
> definitions of existing MD arrays
>
> This configuration was auto-generated on Thu, 17 Mar 2022 16:19:20 +0530 by mkconf
> ARRAY /dev/md/NAS:0 metadata=1.2 name=NAS:0 UUID=e1965c11:b3f7c3db:68417477:2663bfbf

```
sudo mount /dev/md/NAS:0 /mnt/md0
```

Output;

> mount: /mnt/md0: bad option; for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might need a /sbin/mount.(type) helper program.

```
sudo fsck.ext4 -v /dev/sda2
```

Output;

> e2fsck 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
> ext2fs_check_desc: Corrupt group descriptor: bad block for inode bitmap
> fsck.ext4: Group descriptors look bad... trying backup blocks...
> fsck.ext4: Bad magic number in super-block while using the backup 
> blocksfsck.ext4: going back to original superblock
> Superblock has an invalid journal (inode 8).
> Clear? yes
> *** journal has been deleted ***
> The filesystem size (according to the superblock) is 1953443072 blocks
> The physical size of the device is 976721408 blocks
> Either the superblock or the partition table is likely to be corrupt!
> Abort? yes
> /dev/sda2: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****

I have aborted above process. Should I continue?

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1501070/edit) your question and add the output of `sudo mdadm --detail --scan`

Comment: @Terrance No output displayed for sudo mdadm --detail --scan

Comment: Actually, looking at your `lsblk` output it looks like your array was / is ZFS and not mdadm.  I should have caught that earlier.  Maybe see https://askubuntu.com/a/123130/231142

Comment: @Terrance I saw that too. But I don't know how it changed to zfs share and I'm sure I have used the guide linked above to create the Raid 5 array. ZFS not even installed in the system. Running the command 'sudo zfs get all' gives the error  'zfs: command not found' and as I mentioned above raid was working fine until the motherboard replacement.

Comment: You might have to clear out what you have tried.  I'm not 100% sure, but it might be the name of `/dev/md/NAS:0` in the command that you used may be a bad name.  The only time I have seen a `:` used is like in a CIFS mount that is pointed to another system, but I have never seen a local device name with a `:` in it.  If also that the `lsblk` listing partitions are correct, you would be assembling the RAID by partitions which would be using the `sda2`, `sdb2` and `sdc2` partitions.  In the how to guide you have there they started with blank drives, then partitioned after the RAID was created.

Comment: I would also look into recovering the superblocks on those drives.  I decent guide for superblock recovery https://linuxexpresso.wordpress.com/2010/03/31/repair-a-broken-ext4-superblock-in-ubuntu/  Once a good superblock on the drive(s) is recovered the command I had you type in first should be able to see the existing RAID array that was on them.

Comment: @Terrance Should I continue the process as per the last output I have added?

Comment: You can try rebooting the system then run the command  of `sudo mdadm --detail --scan` and see if it shows any output.  The command is safe as it only scans for what was existing, and if the output is successful, the output is what is needed to be added to the `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` file to load the array.

Comment: @Terrance nope still no output. Should I continue with command sudo fsck.ext4 -v /dev/sda2 ?

Comment: Sorry, yes, rerun the checks on the drive(s).

Comment: @Terrance      It just goes on <br />.
Group descriptor 32895 checksum is 0x0000, should be 0x102d.  FIXED.
Block bitmap for group 32896 is not in group.  (block 11404697244042371)
Relocate<y>? cancelled!
Inode bitmap for group 32896 is not in group.  (block 17597146731742339)
Relocate<y>? cancelled!
Inode table for group 32896 is not in group.  (block 34204170357736579)
WARNING: SEVERE DATA LOSS POSSIBLE.
Relocate<y>? cancelled!
Group descriptor 32896 checksum is 0x0018, should be 0xac0c.  FIXED.


/dev/sda2: ********** WARNING: Filesystem still has errors **********

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Managed to recover data by just rebuilding the array from scratch. I did a fresh install of OMV and wiped 3 hdds using gui. Then created a new raid 5 array and it started resyncing. After resyncing is done the array is mounting and files are accessible again.**